# No results yet no error with N-Tier Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-5, n-tier-architecture

I have created a demo project using the N-Tier Entity Framework VS2012.

the problem is that there are no results returned no mather what i request.

No Errors are thrown of detected?

Any suggestions here are welcome?

Comment: Suggestion: show your code. Do you even have data in your data source?

Comment: @user2003638 Please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call the AsQueriable() method for requesting data from the backend.

N-Tier Entity Framework supports both, local and remote queries. While e.g. *context.Orders.ToList()* only returns what’s already in client memory, you can call *context.Orders.**AsQueriable()**.ToList()* to make the query to be executed on the server.

You may also want to consult the framework’s user guide found at http://ntieref.codeplex.com/ for some step-by-step guidance.