# N-Tier Entity Framework fails with join query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I'm developing a VS2010 solution based on this framework: http://ntieref.codeplex.com/.
Everything is ok, and I can query my database (MS SQLServer 2008) and save changes.

Now I'm trying to query a table (Projects) joining it with another one (project-user association) and filtering by key (user key) like this:

```
var query = from p in ctx.C__E_PROJECTS.AsQueryable()
            join pu in ctx.CUMR_USER_PROJECTS_ASSOCIATION.AsQueryable() on p.CD_PROJECT equals pu.RF_PROJECT
            where pu.RF_USER == 1
            select p;
```

but I get a [System.NotImplementedException] = {"The method or operation is not implemented."} at 
NTier.Client.Domain\QueryProvider.cs:line 382 (which is part of N-Tier Entity Framework library).

Also replacing the join like this gives the same exception:

```
var query2 = from p in ctx.C__E_PROJECTS.AsQueryable()
             from pu in ctx.CUMR_USER_PROJECTS_ASSOCIATION.AsQueryable()
             where p.CD_PROJECT == pu.RF_PROJECT
                && pu.RF_USER == 1
             select p;
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there another way to get a table filtered in join with another table?

This is the definition of the two tables:
(where Entity is NTier.Common.Domain.Model.Entity)

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(C__E_PROJECT_VERSIONS))]
[KnownType(typeof(CUMR_USER_PROJECTS_ASSOCIATION))]
[MetadataType(typeof(C__E_PROJECTSMetadata))]
public class C__E_PROJECTS : Entity<C__E_PROJECTS>, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public C__E_PROJECTS();

    [DataMember]
    [NavigationProperty]
    public TrackableCollection<C__E_PROJECT_VERSIONS> C__E_PROJECT_VERSIONS { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    [SimpleProperty]
    [ServerGeneration(1)]
    [Key]
    public int CD_PROJECT { get; set; }
    [NavigationProperty]
    [DataMember]
    public TrackableCollection<CUMR_USER_PROJECTS_ASSOCIATION> CUMR_USER_PROJECTS_ASSOCIATION { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [SimpleProperty]
    public string DS_PROJECT { get; set; }
    [SimpleProperty]
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public string ID_PROJECT { get; set; }

    protected override void ClearNavigationProperties();
    protected override int GetKeyHashCode();
    protected override bool IsKeyEqual(C__E_PROJECTS entity);
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    [KnownType(typeof(CUME_USERS))]
    [MetadataType(typeof(CUMR_USER_PROJECTS_ASSOCIATIONMetadata))]
    [KnownType(typeof(C__E_PROJECTS))]
    public class CUMR_USER_PROJECTS_ASSOCIATION : Entity<CUMR_USER_PROJECTS_ASSOCIATION>, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        public CUMR_USER_PROJECTS_ASSOCIATION();

        [NavigationProperty]
        [DataMember]
        public C__E_PROJECTS C__E_PROJECTS { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        [SimpleProperty]
        public bool? CAN_READ { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        [NavigationProperty]
        public CUME_USERS CUME_USERS { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [SimpleProperty]
        public int RF_PROJECT { get; set; }
        [SimpleProperty]
        [Key]
        [DataMember]
        [Required]
        public int RF_USER { get; set; }

        protected override void ClearNavigationProperties();
        protected override int GetKeyHashCode();
        protected override bool IsKeyEqual(CUMR_USER_PROJECTS_ASSOCIATION entity);
    }
```

As a workaround I've implemented the join query in a SQL Server stored procedure which returns the query result and I added the stored procedure to the edmx model. Everything ok.
Now saving the edmx or running the "N-Tier Entity Generator" custom tool I expected to have the related function in the context at client side, but it is missing. I can see it in the XXX.Server.Domain.Repositories project, but it is not propagated to the client. Do I have to edit the T4 templates?

Thank you!
Roberto

Comment: could you remove the extension Method `AsQueryable()`. And try.

Comment: why do you need to call .AsQueryable()

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I think .AsQueryable() is required from the N-Tier Entity Framework to make the call to the remote webservice. It is used in the samples and in the library documentation: [link](http://ntieref.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: Better explained here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397592/no-results-yet-no-error-with-n-tier-entity-framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397592/no-results-yet-no-error-with-n-tier-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In general ...**

N-Tier Entity Framework generates client and server code to query entities supporting sorting (orderby etc.), filtering (where), paging (skip and take), and including relations (include). This operations are end-to-end i.e. client define linq queries, transmitted to server via WCF and eventually executed on the database. More sophisticated query operations like projections, aggregations, and joins can be added manually either on server (DataService) or client data context (DataContext). All relevant interfaces and classes are generated as partial and my easily be extended using partial interfaces and classes:

on server

```
-   partial interface IMyDataService
-   partial class MyDataService
```

and on client

```
-   partial interface IMyDataContext
-   partial class MyDataContext
```

Also, stored procedures are not automatically exposed by the framework generated code. If you would like so, either modify code generation (T4 files) or add custom methods to data service and client data context.

**In your case ...**

Depending on what your intension is you could do something like:

```
var query = 
  from p in ctx.PROJECTS.AsQueryable()
                        .Include(“USER_PROJECTS_NAVIGATION_PROPERTY”)
  where p.USER_PROJECTS_NAVIGATION_PROPERTY.RF_USER == 1
  select p;
```

Or if you need something more complex, implement it as a custom method using the partial classes listed above.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I've extended the partial classes (on server and client sides) and I can get the desired data from the db.

Comment: I have a problem though: I have the data in a QueryResult<C__E_PROJECTS> on the client; how can I get I merged in the context's table?
I tried calling Attach in a loop, like this

`var result = ctx.GetProjectsByUser(new ClientInfo(), 1);

foreach(var project in result.Data)
{
    ctx.C__E_PROJECTS.Attach(project);
}`
but just after attaching the first item I get the table populated with all the item in the db. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Attaching an entity to client data context automatically attaches all related entities (i.e. parent and child entities accessible via navigation properties) to client data context as well.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your update ,try this:

```
var query = from p in ctx.PROJECTS.AsQueryable().Include("USER_PROJECTS_ASSOCIATION")
            from q in p.USER_PROJECTS_ASSOCIATION.AsQueryable()
            where q.USER_PROJECTS_ASSOCIATION.RF_USER==1
            select p; // or try Select q;
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: It gives the same exception. I downloaded the source code of the N-Tier Entity Framework libraries and I tried to debug it: when using 'join' or more than a 'from' in the query, it ends in a method which throws the NotImplemented exception. I'll try to figure out if it's possible to implement the method.

Comment: And when you do with only one entity?

Comment: Also with the query of your updated answer it gives the NotImplemented exception. With only one entity it works correctly. The query in your comment is working fine (with ctx instead of p).

Comment: If you have the result from this query. I removed it because of the ctx missing. Then could you do the first query comparing to the result of the second query where `RF_USER==1`

Comment: Yes, thanks, this can be a solution for this query, considering the amount of data (of the project table, which would be unfiltered) is limited, but this is only a simple case. I will need more complex query in other parts of my application. What I'm trying to understand is if N-Tier Entity Framework is good for my purpose. I can say that it is a very good library and I want to say thanks to the developer (@ChristofSenn) for his work. But in this moment I'm not sure if it can fulfill my requirements. I hope Christof will have a look at this question.

Comment: What I can advice you is to use just entity Framework